# Extracting multiple, non-adjacent fields from line.split()

Tags: python, list, split, indices

Trying to improve a log parser for Shoutcast, using Python.

Given this log entry line :

```
line = "207.86.121.131 207.86.121.131 2012-11-27 13:02:17 /stream?title=Joe%20Bonamassa%20%2D%20I%20Got%20All%20You%20Need 200 iTunes%2F10%2E7%20%28Windows%3B%20Microsoft%20Windows%207%20x64%20Home%20Premium%20Edition%20Service%20Pack%201%20%28Build%207601%29%29%20AppleWebKit%2F536%2E26%2E9 622592 27 184464"
```

How would I extract fields `0, 5, 8`?

My output should be `207.86.121.131      200       27`

when i try `line.split()[0]` (or 5 or 8) individually, I get that field,

but if I try `line.split()[0,5,8]` I get an error that says

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
```

If instead I try `line.split()[[0,5,8]]` I get an error that says

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list
```

So, is there a way to extract these 3 fields using just the one line.split ?

Comment: where is 0 ,5,8 in ur line

Comment: That's fields 0, 5, and 8

Comment: Solved w itemgetter thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can use `itemgetter`.

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> itemgetter(0,5,8)(line.split())
('207.86.121.131', '200', '27')
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to store the list that `line.split()` returns, and then get the indices:

```
>>> splitted = line.split()
>>> fields = (x[0], x[5], x[8])
>>> print(fields)
('207.86.121.131', '200', '27')
```

Or if you want a one liner, you can use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#enumerate) and a list comprehension:

```
>>> fields = [x for i, x in enumerate(line.split()) if i in (0, 5, 8)]
>>> print fields
['207.86.121.131', '200', '27']
```

Answer (score 1):

May you try this:

```
' '.join([x for i, x in enumerate(line.split()) if i in (0, 5, 8)])
```

and the result is:

```
'207.86.121.131 200 27'
```